# Is there anyway to get types interfaces for request, response in Nest.js with Fastify

Tags: typescript, nestjs, fastify

I am learing Nest.js and on the beging of documentation I read that I can use it not only with **express** but also with **fastify** so I setuped up my first project with **fastify** then I started to read about controllers and I found a problem. For example if I want to get more information about user request i can slightly use `@Req req: Reguest` and this **req** is type of **Request** and it is very easy to get this interface from **express** based application, yuo only have to install `@types/express` and then you can inport **Request** interface from **express** but how(if it is possible) I can get **Request** interface if I am using **fastify**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I lay down that types for **fasify** are already inside Nest projects because they are coming from `@types/node`. If you want to use interfaces fro **fastify** just import them from **fastify** module.
Example:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Query, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { DefaultQuery } from 'fastify';

@Controller('math')
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('add')
  addTwoNumbers(@Query() query: DefaultQuery): number {
    return this.appService.addTwoNumbers(query.value);
  }
}
```

> If you want to read more about types in **fastify** visit this link: [Fastify Types](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/TypeScript/)

Comment: I'm using nestjs and fastify... I want to type my @Res but I'm not able to find the correct type/import. The import { Reply } from 'fastify'; returns an error message: Cannot find module 'fastify' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Answer (score 1):

Install the `fastify` package and import `FastifyRequest` and `FastifyReply` from there:

```
import { Controller, Get, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from 'fastify';

@Controller('feature')
export class FeatureController {
  @Get()
  async handler(
    @Req() req: FastifyRequest,
    @Res() reply: FastifyReply,
  ) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be types from `@types/fastify` that you can install. I believe Fastify uses `Request` and `Reply` as Request and Response.

Comment: No there is no any :/ but actually i found solution. Fastify provides interfaces with ```@types/node``` and you can import them from ```'fastify'``` for example DefaultQuery. So if you have installed ```@types/node```(for nest they are already inside the project so you do not have to) you can easy acces them. Here i found my solution [fastifyTypes](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/TypeScript/#core-types)

Comment: Do you know if express supports that kind of interface?